# How to draw a pentagon using javaFX

Tags: javafx

I have been given an assignment to draw a polygon inside another polygon and cause it to move about the screen upon runtime. I managed to whip up something but then only the first pentagon is showing and it is not even moving about the screen when I run it. Please help me. The code is below;

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.scene.Group;

import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javafx.util.Duration;




public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        //Creating a Polygon
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        //Creating a Group object
        Group root = new Group(polygon);

        //Creating a scene object
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 800);


        //Adding coordinates to the polygon
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                200.0, 300.0,
                300.0, 600.0,
                700.0, 600.0,
                800.0, 300.0,
                500.0, 100.0,
        });
        polygon.setFill(Color.GREENYELLOW);

        //Creating a Polygon
        Polygon smallpolygon = new Polygon();

        //Adding coordinates to the polygon
        smallpolygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                350.0, 250.0,
                400.0, 650.0,
                600.0, 650.0,
                650.0, 250.0,
                500.0, 90.0,
        });

        smallpolygon.setFill(Color.RED);


        //Setting title to the Stage
        stage.setTitle("Drawing a Polygon");

        //Adding scene to the stage
        stage.setScene(scene);

        //Displaying the contents of the stage
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And below is the code that is supposed to make my pentagons move upon runtime;

Comment: 1. You never add the `smallPloygon` to the `root` of the scene. 2. There is no code to animate the polygon, so it doesn't move.

Answer (score 0):

Using mouse click note the 5 points coordinates. Then just pass those X point and Y points in function name strokePolygon(double x array, double y array).